# How to fix Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Trying to set session
like =>

```
Session::set('hello', "hello");
```

But getting this error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()
```

How do I fix this?

this is my composer

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^7.0.0",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "^4.3",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}

I tried:-

```
Session::set()->put('hello', "hello");

Session::put('hello', "hello");

Session(['hello', "hello"]);
```

But no luck.

I have researched it over the internet saying its a bug in Laravel so how do I fix this?

or Any alternative way to set session?

Answer (score 8):

you can use

```
session()->put('hello', 'hello');
```

and check the session driver in env file. put

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

in env

Answer (score 2):

use

```
session()->put('hello', 'hello');
```

You can see how use session in the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#session-usage